# How to run an ionic v1 project today in 2021

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am facing multiple issues while running the Ionic one app. I am running into different problems when I run npm install etc. Can anyone help me out with how to run an ionic one project in 2021? What should be the Ionic version? What will be the Cordova version?
Below is the package.json.

```
{
"name": "project1",
"version": "1.1.1",
"description": "project1: An Ionic project",
"dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-fabric-plugin": "^1.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "~4.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "~1.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/v1-toolkit": "3.2.15",
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "ionic-img-cache": "^1.1.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-device"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"cordova": {
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-file": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
        "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {},
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-fabric-plugin": {
            "FABRIC_API_KEY": "",
            "FABRIC_API_SECRET": ""
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It is so old you may be better off starting a new ionic project and copying the code into the new project.

Comment: i share something pz see https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/getting-started/